# Blender UVs are unwrapped with (an unwanted) -90 degree rotation

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I ran into a new problem that I have never experienced before.  My UVs are automatically rotated -90 degrees when unwrapped.  This is also happening to default meshes such as the cube.  I understand that I can manually rotate the UVs after the unwrap but I flat out do not want to do this every time I am working with UVs. I want them to unwrap as they should.  Thank you for any help you may provide.